# Eclipse Helios plug in behemoth (I like to write behemoth on everything)

Tags: eclipse, helios

just changed from Netbeans to Eclipse just for fun (Only developer on the company, So I can code on whatever and with whatever I feel like.) That's why I liked the new version of netBeans over vim, it could load resources or plugins, I am not quite aware of their naming conventions, on demand. For example if you were working on a Grails project it would only load grails related resources.

On Eclipse I have a gazillion plugins installed. Some to emulate Netbeans functionality (Grails, JavaFX, Ruby, PHP, CSS, Python, etc.) And some others Netbeans lacks (Android, Vaadin, SpringRoo, Git and some others) But I am not sure how Eclipse handles this plug in behemothing

Does it load them on demand? Do I have to manually disable the ones I am not using? Do I have to have different installs for each language I work on? Or do I have to learn how to live with this big mess of plugins in order to have everything I need at hand??

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Eclipse loads the plug-in codes lazily. On the other hand, the menu/toolbar contributions are loaded at the start of the platform.

If the plug-ins are written correctly, they should not interfere with each other, and the unnecessary elements should be few in the context menus.

My suggestion is to try this installation, and look for potential problems. If you have problems with the environment, only then try to identify and remove the plug-ins. But it should be ok.

Comment: Great!! thanks. That's what I wanted to know. I tried this installation and it really works flawlessly. Just the dashboards and panels of aptana and SpringSource, but it really is no biggie.